# Как обратиться к объекту который на другой форме? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Как обратиться к объекту который на другой форме? Вот код:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Language = Object.SelectedValue.ToString();
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

`Object` это сам объект который на `Form4` , а нужно чтобы он работал и на `Form1`! `Modifiers` включён на `public`. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Создайте публичный метод во второй форме, который вернет нужное значение. А так, вопрос не понятен, возможно у вас ошибки в коде, поэтому и не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас Form1 напрямую создаёт Form4, то в Form4 достаточно сделать так:

```
class Form4 : Form
{
   public object Object;
}
```

Тогда из Form1, где вы запускаете Form4, можно будет обратиться к полю Object, например:

```
class Form1 : Form
{
   Form4 form4;
   void КакаятоФункцияГдеСоздаётсяИОткрываетсяForm4()
   {
      form4 = new Form4();
      form4.Show();
   }
   void КакаятоФункцияГдеЧитаемObjectИзForm4()
   {
      if (form4 != null)
      {
         var obj = form4.Object;
         Properties.Settings.Default.Language = obj.SelectedValue.ToString();
         Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
      }
   }
}
```